# Errno 13 Permission denied for downloading files

Tags: python

I'm trying to download zip files from a url, and place them in a directory

```
import requests 

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size=128):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/1994/NOV/cm23NOV1994bhav.csv.zip'
save_path = 'D:/folder/Programming/Python/trading/Bhavcopy/'

download_url(url,save_path)
```

I get the following output

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "d:\folder\Programming\Python\trading\bhavcopy.py", line 12, in
> module
> download_url(url,save_path)   File "d:\folder\Programming\Python\trading\bhavcopy.py", line 5, in
> download_url
> with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/folder/Programming/Python/trading/Bhavcopy/'

NOTE: I am logged into windows as an admin and have full rights. How do I pass the rights to the python file write into a directory which will be made by python itself

Comment: For a start, this doesn't seem to have any relation to downloading, as the topic suggests. This seems to be a simple permissions problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trading/Bhavcopy.` is a directory.  You can't write to a directory.  You need to append a file name to `save_path`.

Comment: Doing this takes away the error but seems like windows is now just creating a zip file, my file is actually downloaded from the web. Can you please help me with this as well ?

Comment: Still seems to be the answer to your question above. Maybe not to your next question, but still.

Comment: Your code downloads a zip file.  Are you saying you are surprised that you're getting a zip file?